# Does equality of characteristic polynomials guarantee equivalence of matrices?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, characteristic-polynomial

I have a qualifying exam coming up in a couple days and I am just trying to understand some pathological examples I have in my notes. I will list a similar problem which I know the solution to and then the question.

True or False:   let $A,B \in \mathbb{Q}^{n \times n }$  Suppose $xI-A$ and $xI-B$ are equivalent then $\det(xI-A) = \det(xI-B)$.

I wrote in my notes this is true because any two matrices are equivalent in $\mathbb{Q[x]}^{n \times n}$ if and only if they have the same invariant factors.  Since the characteristic polynomial is a product of the invariant factors it follows that $\det(xI-A) = \det(xI-B)$.

> True or False:   let $A,B \in \mathbb{Q}^{n \times n }$. If $\det(xI-A) = \det(xI-B)$ (in $\mathbb{Q}[x]$) then $xI-A$ and $xI-B$ are equivalent  in $\mathbb{Q}[x]^{n \times n}$

I think this is false because of the fact that equality of determinants is not strong enough to guarantee all invariant factors are equal but I do not have an example.

Comment: $\begin{pmatrix}1&0\\0&1\end{pmatrix}$ and $\begin{pmatrix}1&1\\0&1\end{pmatrix}$ have the same characteristic polynomial, but are not similar.

Comment: I meant $A$ equivalent to $B$ in the sense that $\exists P, Q$ invertible matrices so that $B = PAQ$.  Are those two matrices you listed above still a counterexample if you replace similar by equivalent?

Comment: The characteristic polynomial is **not** preserved by these operations.

Comment: @user7980: Under that notion of equivalence, two matrices are equivalent if and only if they have the same rank.

Comment: In the same vein as J. M.’s comment, I suggest, dear user7980, the following exercise: Which n by n matrices have the same characteristic polynomial as the zero matrix?

Comment: Thank you but I am a little confused by your comments.  Can I conclude that If $\det(xI-A) = \det(xI-B)$ then $xI-A$ and $xI-B$ are equivalent from what you have said?

Comment: No, you cannot. If $A$ and $B$ are the two example matrices from the comment by J.M., then the characteristic polynomials are the same. The invariant factors of $xI-A$ are both $x-1$, but the invariant factors of $xI-B$ are $1$ and $(x-1)^2$. Hence $xI-A$ and $xI-B$ are not in that relation $B=PAQ$ for any invertible matrices $P,Q$ with entries in $\mathbf{Q}[x]$.

Comment: No, you can't, they all tried to give you counterexamples.
@Jyrki: Actually the matrices in J.M.'s comments are equivalent, though not similar.

Comment: Thank you everyone for all your comments. This makes sense to me now.

Comment: @zulon: The OP specified interest in the equivalence of $xI-A$ and $xI-B$, **not** in the equivalence of $A$ and $B$. When dealing with transformations over the Euclidean domain $\mathbf{Q}[x]$, the invariant factors tell the whole story. If we allow elementary transformations over a field (such as $\mathbf{Q}(x)$), then the rank is sufficient information to determine equivalence.

Comment: @Jirki: Not that is matters, but the OP asked several questions, in the question and in the comments, and one of them *is* about the equivalence of $A$ and $B$. [I agree with everything else you said, and found your comments very illuminating!]

Comment: @Pierre-Yves: Ok. It seems to me that several of us were shooting at moving targets. I should have waited for things to converge, before I comment. Hopefully no harm was done!

Comment: From Arturo's (now deleted) answer, apparently the notion of *defective* versus *derogatory* matrices is crucial here.

Comment: I suppose I should have linked to [this question](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/14075) to begin with...

Answer (score 37, accepted):

You've been given easy examples to show that the characteristic polynomial does not suffice to determine similarity of matrices. Here's a nice related problem:

**Proposition.** If $n\leq 3$, then two matrices are similar if and only if they have the same characteristic polynomial and the same minimal polynomial.

*Proof.* That similar matrices have the same characteristic and minimal polynomials is immediate. Assume now that $A$ and $B$ are $n\times n$ matrices with the same minimal and characteristic polynomials; we aim to show that $A$ and $B$ are similar.

The result is trivial for $n=1$.

If the characteristic polynomial splits, then we have three cases: either the characteristic polynomial splits into distinct linear factors, in which case both matrices are diagonalizable with the same eigenvalues, hence similar; or the characteristic polynomial has repeated factors. If the characteristic polynomial is equal to a pure power (either $(x-a)^2$ or $(x-a)^3$, then the minimal polynomial completely determines the Jordan canonical form of the matrix: diagonalizable if the minimal polynomial is $(x-a)$; a block of size $2\times 2$ (and one of size $1\times 1$ if $n=3$) if the minimal polynomial is $(x-a)^2$; and a single Jordan block of size $3\times 3$ if the minimal polynomial is $(x-a)^3$; hence the two matrices have the same Jordan canonical form, and so they are similar. If the minimal polynomial is of the form $(x-a)^2(x-b)$ with $a\neq b)$, then the two matrices are diagonalizable if the minimal polynomial is $(x-a)(x-b)$; and both have a Jordan canonical form consisting of a $2\times 2$ block associated to $a$ and a $1\times 1$ block associated to $b$ if the minimal polynomial is $(x-a)^2(x-b)$. Either way, the two matrices have the same Jordan canonical form, hence they are similar.

If the characteristic polynomial does not split, then it is either irreducible cubic, or a product of an irreducible quadratic and a linear factor; either way, the characteristic polynomial must equal the minimal polynomial, so the two matrices have the same rational canonical form, hence they are similar. **QED**

However, as soon as you get to $4\times 4$ matrices, the result is no longer true. Specifically, the matrices
$$\left(\begin{array}{cccc}
0 & 1 & 0 & 0\\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0\\
0 & 0 & 0 & 1\\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0
\end{array}\right)\qquad\text{and}\qquad
\left(\begin{array}{cccc}
0 & 1 & 0 & 0\\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0\\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0\\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0
\end{array}\right)$$
both have characteristic polynomial $x^4$ and minimal polynomial $x^2$, but since their Jordan canonical forms are different, they are not similar.

So: the characteristic polynomial by itself suffices to determine similarity only in the trivial $1\times 1$ case; the characteristic and the minimal together determine similarity in the $2\times 2$ and $3\times 3$ cases. After that, the minimal and characteristic *may* completely determine similarity in some instances, but generally do not suffice.

As for equivalence, as noted, two matrices are equivalent if and only if they have the same rank. The $4\times 4$ matrices above have different ranks, hence they are not equivalent, but the same characteristic and minimal polynomials,

Comment: Thanks for this great answer. One thing: right after the case the characteristic polynomial is pure for $3\times 3$, you wrote "If the _minimal polynomial_ is of the form $(x-a)^2 (x-b)$ with $a\ne b$", but you mean the _characteristic polynomial_, don't you?

Answer (score 0):

NO

The equality of characteristic of polynomial of matrices does not guarantee  equivalence of matrices:Counterexample

suppose A=$\begin{pmatrix} 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 \end{pmatrix}$
and B=$\begin{pmatrix} 0&1 \\0& 0 \end{pmatrix}$

$p_A(x)=det(A-xI) =det(\begin{pmatrix} -x & 0 \\ 0 & -x \end{pmatrix}) =x^2$
$p_B(x)=det(B-xI) =det(\begin{pmatrix} -x & 1 \\ 0 & -x \end{pmatrix}) =x^2$

$p_A(x) = x^2 =p_B(x)$ but rank(A) $\not=$ rank(B)...>>they are not equivalent.

Comment: This question is $10$ years old and about the equivalence of $xI-A$ and $xI-B$ in $\mathbb Q[x]^{n\times n}$, not about the equivalence of $A$ and $B$ in $\mathbb Q^{n\times n}$.