# Finding out whether two matrices are similar?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

### $\mathbf{B = P^{^-1} A P} \iff$ ($\mathbf{B}$ is similar to $\mathbf{A}$)

I'm a little confused about matrix similarity. Let's say we have the following matrix $A$:

\begin{bmatrix}2&5\\4&1\end{bmatrix}

Its eigenvalues are $6$ and $-3$. Respective eigenvectors $\left<(5,4)\right>, \left<(-1,1)\right>$.

**How do I find out whether its similar to another matrix (B)?**

Let's say matrix $B$:

\begin{bmatrix}4&5\\1&4\end{bmatrix}

Trying to actually find the regular $P$ so that the equation would be satisfied seems like way too much calculating.

My idea is to try and diagonalize both of them - and if I end up with same eigenvalues on the diagonal (in whatever order), then they are both similar? (using the transitive property, since similarity is an equivalence).

Thank you in advance.

Comment: See [this post](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/14075/how-do-i-tell-if-matrices-are-similar)

Comment: Here is http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference for properly displaying functions in future questions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your idea is correct and you can even use it to find the matrix $P$. Diagonalizing $A$, you will find $P_1$ such that $P_1^{-1} A P = D_1$ where $D_1$ is diagonal and the diagonal entries are the eigenvalues of $A$. Diagonalizing $B$, you will find $P_2$ such that $P_2^{-1} B P_2 = D_2$ with $D_2$ diagonal. If the matrices $A$ and $B$ have the same eigenvalues (counting with multiplicities), then you can arrange that $D_1 = D_2$ and then

$$ A = P_1 D_1 P_1^{-1} = P_1 D_2 P_1^{-1} = P_1 P_2^{-1} B P_2 P_1^{-1} = P^{-1} B P $$

where $P = P_2 P_1^{-1}$.

If $A$ and $B$ don't have the same eigenvalues, or $A$ is diagonalizable and $B$ is not or the other way around, then $A$ and $B$ won't be similar. If both $A$ and $B$ are not diagonalizable, you can bring them to a canonical form instead.

Comment: Thank you very much! You have explained it very clearly! Does that also mean that once a matrix is not diagonalizable - it is not similar to any matrix?

Comment: Nope - a non-diagonalizable matrix cannot be similar to a diagonalizable matrix but can be similar to many other non-diagonalizable matrices.

Comment: Just checked it, you are right! Non-diagonalizable matrices are always similar to other non-diagonalizable matrices (multiplying non-D by any choice of regular inv(P) and P will result in another non-D matrix). Thanks a lot, really appreciate the help! :)