# How to prove two matrices are similar

Tags: linear-algebra

I have the two matrices:

$\begin{pmatrix}1&-4&-2\\ 0&1&0\\ 0&4&3\end{pmatrix}$ and $\begin{pmatrix}3&0&0\\ \:0&1&1\\ \:0&0&1\end{pmatrix}$

I know they have the same trace and determinant but I know that isn't enough to prove they are similar... what are the next steps I should take?
Is proving they have the same eigenvalues enough to show they are similar?

Comment: The first matrix is already in Jordan normal form...

Comment: Do you have studied matrix reduction?

Comment: For characteristic $2$ the first matrix is diagonal, but the second is not diagonalizable. Hence they cannot be similar in this case.

Comment: And spoiler: they aren't similar. Just compute the Jordan normal form.

Comment: @DietrichBurde nope. The first matrix - $I$ has kernel dimension 2, unlike the second one.

Comment: @DietrichBurde $(0,-4,-2)$ and $(0,4,2)$ look pretty linearly dependent to me.

Comment: We haven't learned Jordan normal form yet. All we learned is B=P^−1AP and I'm not sure how to come up with a P (or I guess since they aren't similar there won't be a P? I'm not sure how to prove that)

Comment: @user520403 You do not need Jordan form. Just compute the system of linear equations with the $9$ variables being the entries of $P$ coming from $PA=BP$. Then you get $\det(P)=0$ from it, so they are not similar.

Answer (score 2):

The first matrix is diagonalizable, namely $P^{-1}AP={\rm diag}(1,1,3)$ with
$$
P=\begin{pmatrix} -3 & 2 & -2\cr -2 & 1 & 0 \cr 4 & -2 & 2 \end{pmatrix}.
$$
The second matrix is not diagonalizable, so they are in fact not similar.

Answer (score 1):

Hint: The definition of similarity between matrices is the following:

Two square matrices of the same dimensions A and B are said to be similar if there is a matrix P such that $$B = P^{-1}AP$$

Try finding a matrix $P$ for your exercise.

Answer (score 1):

Hint: A matrix $A$ and $B$ are said to be similar if 
$$B=P^{-1}AP$$
for some invertible matrix $P$. This link: [How do I tell if matrices are similar?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/14075/how-do-i-tell-if-matrices-are-similar]) outlines the entire process.